Understanding an answer to an MIT opencourseware Statistics for Applications question
I have a question about the answer to this question taken from the MIT opencourseware Statistics for Applications. The answer is taken from a user on github and isn't an official answer. My question is why does this person answering this question bother using a normal distribution here to approximate the binomial distribution? I don't understand this persons thought process. Surely by using a normal distribution here they have just introduced needless error?
As far as I can tell they want a cleaner/easier to use equation for the CDF but working with a bionomial distribution directly should be easier? no?
The question:

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p \in [0,1]$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, let $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

a) What is the distribution of $n\bar{X}_n$?
b) Prove that $\bar{X}_n$ converges to $p$ in $L^2$?

The Answer:
We have:
$$ E[X_n] = p $$
$$ V[X_n] = \frac{p(1 - p)}{n} $$
In addition:
$$ n\overline{X}_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{n\overline{X}_n - \mu_n}{\sigma_n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i - p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1 - p)}{n}}} \sim N(0,1) \quad (\text{Central Limit Theorem}) $$
$$ \Rightarrow P\left(\frac{n\overline{X}_n - p}{\sqrt{p(1 - p)}} \leq t\right) = \Phi(t) $$
$$ \Rightarrow P\left(n\overline{X}_n \leq \sqrt{tp(1 - p)} + p\right) = \Phi(t) $$
$$ \Rightarrow P(n\overline{X}_n \leq x) = \Phi\left(\frac{x - pn}{\sqrt{p(1 - p)}}\right) $$
$$ \Rightarrow F_n(x) = \Phi\left(\frac{x - pn}{\sqrt{p(1 - p)}}\right) $$
(1) is the CDF of distribution of $ n\overline{X}_n $. We have:
$$ E[(\overline{X}_n - p)^2] = E[\overline{X}_n^2] - 2pE[\overline{X}_n] + p^2 $$
$$ = \frac{\sigma_n}{n} + (E[\overline{X}_n])^2 - 2pE[\overline{X}_n] + p^2 $$
$$ = \frac{p(1 - p)}{n} + p^2 - 2p^2 + p^2 $$
$$ = \frac{p(1 - p)}{n} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}E[(\overline{X}_n - p)^2] = 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \overline{X}_n \text{ converges to } p \text{ in } L^2. $$

The correct answer to (a) is, as you say, a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, not a normal distribution. The  suggested answer to (b) does not seem to use a normal approximation, but just the variance of $\bar X$.  There are various typos in the suggested answer, but when corrected they do not change the argument.

Thank you! this answers my question. The typos are most likely mine (trying to convert from a pdf to stackexchange/latex wasn't easy).
